# How to see HTML representation of test results in CircleCI

Tags: java, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am new to CircleCI. I have configured my `.circleci/config.yml`. My build executed successfully; all tests passed as far as I can see on console. However I'd be glad to see the test report as an HTML as I typically can do with Jenkins.

Is this possible with CircleCI?

This is the relevant part from `config.yml`:

```
  - store_test_results:
      path: build/test-results/test
```

As far as I can see this is the location of test reports as XML files on my local machine.

When build is running it prints the following:

```
    Archiving the following test results
      * /home/circleci/circleci-beanlane/build/test-results/test
```

```
Uploaded
```

Where it uploads the test results to? To other local folder in docker that runs my build? In this case it does not help too much.

I saw in one project that people upload test results to s3. This is not possible in my case because I am working on my private project and do not have s3 storage. Moreover reports even stored in s3 cannot be viewed directly using web browser; they better should be stored under HTTP server.

So, what is the simplest solution to make my test reports accessible?

Comment: `upload_artifacts` is what you are looking for, it will put all the files in the artifacts tab https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/artifacts/#uploading-artifacts

Comment: To follow on from @Drazisil's comment, the Artefacts tab is in the build/job screen in the CircleCI dashboard.

Comment: Drazisil I used store_artifacts: as well , however in jenkins it was much better